# "It usually is" vs "it is usually"

Tags: grammar, adverb-position

It is very common to use the verb 'to be' before adverbs of frequency as in the following example:

> Her cake is *usually* tasty.

However, I came across the following construction in which the verb 'to be' is used after the adverb of frequency:

> Her cake wasn't as good as it *usually* is.

I was wondering why the verb 'to be' appeared after the adverb of frequency in the last construction.

Comment: But they didn't mention why or what linguistic rules explain the two uses.

Comment: I am not sure there is any rule. Sometimes, for emphasis, the adverb can be put before an auxiliary verb or "Be". For example--Person A: "Be on time tomorrow." Person B: "I _always_ am!". You see he could have said "I am _always_ on time!", but without the noun/adjective/prepositional phrase normally accompanying "Be" as a main verb, the adverb sounds better before the verb. Remember that adverbs are just about the only flexible POS in English. You probably noticed that in the duplicate that I marked the 2 answers did not agree with each other, and depended mainly _on the way it sounded_.

Comment: @Cascabe: Your comment is valuable and it has what l am looking for. Thanks a lot.